# Referencing a row from another table c# linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I want to use an id from one table to list a title from another table in wpf, so i did this:

```
 var q = from a in context.associations
                select a;

        associations = q.ToList();
        associationViewSource.Source = associations;

        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            var qTitles = from b in context.textbooks
                          where b.Id == item.book_id
                          select b.Title;



            assocListView.ItemsSource = qTitles.ToList();
        }
```

in the first portion of the code i am making the main body of the information, it lists all the information from associations table, after that i want to list the relevant titles from textbooks table, thats where i add items to the assocListview, but it of course fails and the data isn't  displayed, no errors are thrown either. i hope i was clear enough.
Please help

Comment: what type is b.Id? Can you ensure the comparer actually works for that data type? I mean, it could be that `b.Id == item.book_id` isn't matching thus it completes but you get no titles.

Comment: they are both ints and yeah they should be fine

Comment: As @Anthony mentions... are you sure that setting `assocListView.ItemsSource` each time per iteration is correct?

Comment: won't qTitles hold only the last record instead of all of them if i remove it from the iteration?

Comment: Yes, but it also does with the way you have it now. You need to append them in each iteration... either in a variable of its own, and then set it outside; or append in each iteration (since I don't much about WPF I don't know if the latter is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of `Titles` that have `associations` with a join...

```
var qTitles = context.textbooks
                    .Join(context.associations,
                          b => b.Id,
                          a => a.book_id,
                          b => b.Title)
                    .ToList();
```

The intention of the code isn't clear though because `assocListView.ItemsSource` is assigned to in each iteration of the loop. Is that a bug?

Comment: I get a System.ArgumentNullException and the .Join is marked? The code is really really bad, because i am very new to c# and especially it's way of doing database interactions, i come from php

Comment: What I see with the join is that it would require more trips to the database as he still needs context.associations as source a on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting `assocListView.ItemsSource` each pass through the loop, the resultant list will have the results of the last query.

If you want a list of all associated titles you can get it with a single query:

```
var titles = 
    from a in context.associations
    join b in context.textbooks on a.book_id equals b.Id
    select b.Title;

assocListView.ItemsSource = titles.ToList();
```

This will return every title linked to any record in your associations table, in no particular order, with duplicates, etc.  Normally it makes sense to extract a little more information to make it more usable.  For instance, define a structure to hold an associated title:

```
public struct AssocTitle
{
    public int AssocID;
    public int BookID;
    public string Title;
}
```

Then query it like:

```
var titles = 
    from a in context.associations
    join b in context.textbooks on a.book_id equals b.Id
    select new AssocTitle { AssocID = a.Id, BookID = b.Id, Title = b.Title };
```

Then when you click on things in the list view you can find out which book and which association, even if you have lots of associations with the same titles.